# Can we reverse the digits of a number using Array in c?

Tags: arrays, c

Can you please help me to reverse the digits of a number entered by the user using the concept of array in c. I know there is an option given below using which we can reverse the digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n, rev = 0, remainder;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while (n != 0) {
        remainder = n % 10;
        rev = rev * 10 + remainder;
        n /= 10;
    }
    printf("Reversed number = %d", rev);
    return 0;
}
```

Using the above program I can easily reverse the digits.
But I want to use the concept of c to reverse the digits. Let me illustrate how:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    do{
        n=n/10;
        count++;
    }while(n>0);
    
    int i,a[100];
    
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        a[i]=n%10;
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

In the Above code, using ***Do-While*** loop I have counted the no of digits present in the number, so that I can use the count in my for loop.

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        a[i]=n%10;
    }
```

In this for loop I have inserted all the digits of an number in reverse order. So that i can print all these elements using the next for loop which is given below

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
```

This for loop should print all the numbers stored in the array ***a[100]*** in reverse order.
My *expected output* is:

```
     12345
     54321
```

*Output Which I am getting*

```
     12345
     00000
```

Can anyone suggest me the required changes and help me clear my concepts?

Comment: After your `while` loop `n` is zero, so the following logic fails.

Comment: The easiest way to do the task is to read the number *as a string* and reverse it. And a string in C as you know is an array.

Comment: Why do you count the numbers first?

Comment: Why spend time on writing a bad solution when you already have a good one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do{
        n=n/10;
        count++;
    }while(n>0);
```

print `n` after this loop and see if it's value is what you expect. `n` is 0 after this loop.

I'd suggest creating a temporary variable like this:

```
int temp;
```

and assign the value of `n` to `temp`(`temp=n;`).

Now when the do while loop ends, assign `temp` back to `n` so that `n` contains it's initial value.

Also, in this loop,

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        a[i]=n%10;
 }
```

you should do `n=n/10` (like you did while counting the number of digits) after `a[i]=n%10`.

So your final code may look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,count=0;
    int temp;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    temp=n;
    do{
        n=n/10;
        count++;
    }while(n>0);
    n=temp;
    int i,a[100];
    
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        a[i]=n%10;
        n/=10;
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Also, you didn't really need the do while loop to count the number of digits, you could've done this in the first for loop like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int n,count=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int i,a[100];
    for(i=0;n>0;i++){
        a[i]=n%10;
        n/=10;
        count++; //counting the number of digits
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<count;i++){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the way in which you cleared my doubt. You are really a genius. But, why assigning temp=n and n=temp is so important for executing do while loop?

Comment: @VaibhavKatre Since `n` changes to 0 after the do while loop, `a[i]=n%10;` will basically be `a[i]=0%10;`. So with `temp=n`, the initial value of `n` is assigned to `temp` and with `n=temp`, `n` is assigned it's initial value before it changed to 0 after the do while loop.

Comment: @VaibhavKatre Aside: Looking at your code, it seems like you want the user to only input integers greater than 0, if that's the case, you'd want to use a while loop instead of a do while loop (A do while loop executes the statements in the loop body *before* checking the condition).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right you want to put digits from the number into the array in reverse order

```
size_t reverseIntegerToArray(int *buff, unsigned number)
{
    size_t size = 0;

    while(number)
    {
        buff[size++] = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    return size;
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[20];
    size_t size = reverseIntegerToArray(arr, 12345678);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```